# help with sending mail in rails, bad tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendmail

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to send mail through rails:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails-2.1/rails-send-emails.htm

Sendmail wasn't working on my machine, but I got it working when I deployed it.

The problem I'm having is that the @email variables and such don't show up in the mail when it's sent. What is wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try a good tutorial like: http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email

Answer (score 3):

it's because this tutorial is outadated. See the Guide about mailing.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html